# SQL2016 Not able to create Column Master Key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I just installed SQL 2016 Standard Edition because I wanted to use the 'Always Encrypted' feature.
However, when I tried to created a Column Master Key under Security->Always Encrypted Keys->Column Master Key, I got the following error:
[image]

productversion: 13.0.160.5, productlevel:RTM, edition:Standard Edition 64bit
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SSMS 2016 and running the query against a non-2016 instance or vice versa?

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL Management Studio 2016, and SQL Server 2016, Standard edition

Comment: Run a SELECT @@version and paste it into your post just to confirm.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
 Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Do your usual steps, get to the point where you are about to hit ok to generate the key, but instead go to the top of the prompt window and script the command out to a new window.  Run the TSQL and see if you get an error still.

Comment: Ran query in a new window but got the same error

Comment: USE [mydb]
CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY [MK_PersonDOB]
WITH
(
 KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE',
 KEY_PATH = N'CurrentUser/My/blahblah'
)

GO

Comment: Try generating your key through column encryption instead. Right click on a table, click encrypt columns, then follow the wizard to generate a column key and a master key.

Comment: Same error. I actually tried it first and thought it failed because there was no master key. No luck with both of them. I am really confused. Could it be I missed something during installation?

Comment: That would be my last option.  If all else fails, try turning it off and back on again.  Do a full uninstall and try again.

Comment: Same issue here. Not even able to create brand new db on instance, and encrypt columns - @@version = Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB3194716) - 13.0.1722.0 (X64)   Sep 26 2016 13:17:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was probably caused by restoring a SQL2014 database. I backed up a 2014 database and then restored it in 2016. SQL may have seen it as a 2014 schema and therefore complained Column Master Key not supported.
How I resolved it: In SSMS 2016, generate .sql script for the imported database (in Advanced settings, choose SQL 2016 script)
Install a new SQL 2016 instance (which may not be necessary will test) and run the .sql generated, rather than the restore option

Comment: Where do I find the Advanced settings?

Comment: @DovMiller  right click on the database you want to generate a script of -> task -> generate scirpts -> set scripting option. there is a advanced button -> choose script for sql version in advanced option window

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. I fixed it by updating to [Sql Server 2016 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54276) from Sql Server 2016.

Previously `@@version` was:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB3194716) - **13.0.1722.0** (X64)   Sep 26 2016 13:17:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 14393: )

Now `@@version` is:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (**SP1**) (KB3182545) - **13.0.4001.0** (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 14393: )

Note also that my SSMS is totally up to date.

- Tools > Check for Updates > Details - 13.0.16100.1
- A coworker has a slightly older build of SSMS and does not even see the option to encrypt columns.

Comment: Should be marked as the answer, the issue is your SSMS is new enough to support always encrypted but your SQL server version is not.

Answer (score 0):

"Always Encrypted is available in SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and SQL Database. (Prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP1, Always Encrypted was limited to the Enterprise Edition.)"

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017