# Always Encrypted Wizard option not displayed

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server Management Studio updated to v17.4.
I want to use Always Encrypted to encrypt a column. I tried to run the Always Encrypted wizard as illustrated in a number of places. I right click the database node, choose `Tasks` and there's supposed to be an option `Encrypt Columns`, but there isn't.

In the `Security` folder of the database in Management Studio, there's an option of Always Encrypted Keys, but I want to use the wizard.

How can I get the `Encrypt Columns` option to be displayed and display the wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download [Sql Server 2016 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54276) and that solved the problem. I got the direction from a different question, [SQL2016 Not able to create Column Master Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134092/sql2016-not-able-to-create-column-master-key), in seth flowers answer.